# Spring Webapp Error 404 Tomcat doesn't pick up welcome file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm getting error 404 while running a spring webapp.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulrajcse/z8bkuvyn/) for `web.xml`

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulrajcse/kzp670f6/) for `spring-servlet.xml`

I have tried putting it on root folder as well as inside `WEB-INF` and gave proper paths in XML. But it is not working.

Comment: Post the code for your @Controller and the url your are trying to access

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("index");

    }

Answer (score 0):

Please place your welcome.jsp in WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

Now:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>
```

Replace with this

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Now Add the controller mapping as:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomePage() throws Exception {
        return "welcome";

    }
}
```

Will load your welcome page

Comment: I have changed according to your logic, but didnt work.

Comment: I have updated my answer please change your templateResolver bean with viewResolver.

Comment: Yeah I have done that changing to normal viewresolver. But didnt work.
I see only one library under project loaded in tomcat server tab. I have added all libraries in lib folder as well as build path. Why itsnt appearing in server tab? check here:

http://www.imgpuppy.com/images/2016/03/24/dbf88eb4bd32d114ca7be31d31fe5813.jpg

Comment: And no, there's no error in console
This url need to load index.jsp

http://localhost:5757/InsuranceCompanies/